# Eclipse does not start in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, eclipse

I'm new to Ubuntu. I installed Eclipse from Ubuntu Software.
Whenever I go to Applications and click on Eclipse, it just zooms the icon in but does nothing. I'm running dual boot if that is an issue?

Comment: From which source did you install Eclipse ? Is it the snap version ? Also, what do you see if you launch Eclipse from a terminal ?

Comment: I installed it from Ubuntu software. When i launch it , it only displays the starting mini-screen which has eclipse written over it.

Comment: Yes, all these details were already in your original question :) If you open Ubuntu software and go to your installed Eclipse page, you will see at the bottom the source of the package (close to the Eclipse version). Could be Ubuntu repository, snap, flatpak... That was my question. Also, if you open a terminal (CTRL + ALT + T in most flavors) and type "eclipse", you should get some error messages. I would suggest you to edit your question and add these error messages as well as the Eclipse source, that is definitely helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and managed to open it, but I still don't know what is going on. In my case, whenever I open Eclipse it does nothing, but I selected a `.php` file and in the *Open With Other Application* dialog I found *Eclipse* (which I tried and nothing happened). However, I also found *Eclipse IDE* and by selecting that, Eclipse opened normally.

Maybe this can help you and even if it doesn't perhaps someone knows what is going on for me.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 Check for java version

```
java -version:
```

in case no java installed

Step 2

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install openjdk-17-jdk
```

Step 3

```
eclipse
```